# beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I update flutter version and when I run the project it throw these errors:

```
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 5348): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 5348): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 5348): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 5348): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 5348): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
```

**Note:** This project was working properly on an old version of flutter.

Answer (score 1):

Those aren't errors, they're warnings.  And they really aren't important-  it means due to a timing bug, some commands from the keyboard came in after the edit text was no longer focused (remember the soft keyboard is a separate app, so there are cross process delays on commands).  So long as the text is still showing up, it can be ignored.